# Не удалось запустить PostgreSQL-14-Win10 при попытке запустить сервер PostgreSQL-14-Win10 в Open Server на Windows 10. Как решить данную проблему?

Tags: postgresql, openserver

Ошибка 'Не удалось запустить PostgreSQL-14-Win10' при попытке запустить сервер PostgreSQL-14-Win10 в Open Server на Windows 10. Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: посмотрите файл логов PostgreSQL, там должно быть больше подробностей. Обычно он расположен в в директории СУБД + ".\data\logs\"